# Wifi signal antenna

Tags: internet, wifi

Is there any powerful antenna, set on two storey house height to receive wifi signals from provider? 
Is it possible at all to receive wifi signals by hacking it (not from neighbour or around,but signal wave)  or is there any free access source?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement Stack Exchange. This isn't really about "home improvement", and is a bit unclear to boot. Unfortunately, there really isn't a good Stack Exchange site for a question like this; you might try [Googling](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+do+i+get+wifi+in+my+house).

Comment: Websearch "cantenna"  for DIY directional wifi  antenna designs.

Comment: It is related to home somewhat. Well I could not find better place to ask. Thanks to @Richard Crowley I transferred it to EE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your provider offers wireless service (WiMax, 4G, LTE, etc.) then there are external, directional antennas that will extend service to marginal areas. You will need to research exactly what frequency band they are using.

But as Hobbes says, it is not typically "WiFi" as that is meant for LOCAL service inside a home or business.  Unless you are "pirating" WiFi from your neighbors or the coffee shop down the road.

But this question is probably better over in "Electrical Engineering" than here in "Home Improvement".  Perhaps the moderators could consider moving it.

Answer (score 0):

Internet providers generally don't provide wifi, because wifi is a poor system for large-scale networks.
In some cities, free wifi is available and you may be able to use that, but that's both insecure and has poor performance.
There are wifi repeaters and outdoor antennas, they are mostly marketed for use on campsites etc.